# Compile batch file into an EXE file

Tags: c++, batch-file, compilation

I want to compile a batch file into an EXE file using C++. I can get through parsing the batch file and writing a new .cpp file. But I don't know how to compile the new .cpp file into an EXE file for the end user.

OK, here's the thing, I am creating an application in DevC++ that will read in a batch file. Then, one by one parsing it using:

```
system(getline(myfile,line));
```

After setting everything up, I save the newly created file as "main.cpp".

The problem is, I want to compile it into an EXE file, from my program, for the end user.

So basically, can I compile a C++ file from a C++ EXE?

Comment: What happens if you have a `goto` in your batch file? Do you know that if you have a `call file.bat` then you're supposed to return into the file you started from, but if it is simply `file.bat` then you shouldn't?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to reinvent `cmd.exe`. Why?

Comment: If you need test cases, I have plenty :P. And I'm pretty sure that you'll get more things wrong than right. Batch files aren't easily parsable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can provided that the end user has a C++ compiler installed and you're emitting valid C++.

Depending on the compiler you're using, your C++ executable would have to spawn a process that runs

```
cl main.cpp
```

or a similar invocation of the compiler after finishing the translation.

If your user doesn't have a compiler installed, then you're pretty much out of luck - trying to build a C++ compiler yourself is a rather non-trivial exercise.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no. Unless you are willing to write an entire C++ compiler, you will need to invoke an external C++ compiler to compile that .cpp file.

On the plus side, if you are simply looking to convert .BAT files into .EXE files, there are several existing solutions, such as [quickbfc](http://www.abyssmedia.com/quickbfc/).

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask why do you need to parse bat file?

I mean if you are taking input or something from that file then can you try to use a database or something for that?

Also for the user end you can write web application to display output. 
There`s C++ Server Pages equivalent to JSP, PHP which can use C++ classes.

Am I helping here or this is not what you want? may be if you can describe you application use somebody can help you better.